# PHP - Check checkboxes if id is in database, checks first but not next ones?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need to check the checkboxes that id is equal to id from user on database,
Like:
User with ID 1
Permissions table: 1,2,3,4,5

User 1 has permissions of 1,3 and 4
USER   PERM.
1   -   1
1   -   3
1   -   4

With the following code it checks the first permission but not the following ones

```
<?php
   foreach($col2 as $key => $value) {
      foreach($modulosPermissaoFuncio as $checkedModulo){
         if ($value["id"]==$checkedModulo["id_modulo"]){
            $checked1 = "checked";
         }else if($value["id"]<>$checkedModulo["id_modulo"]){
            $checked1 = "";
         }
      }

      echo ' <input type="checkbox" id="'.$value["id"].'" name="checkboxPermissoes[]" value="'.$value["id"].'" '.$checked1.'> &nbsp
      <label for="'.$value["id"].'">'.utf8_decode ( $value["descricao_site"]).'</label><br>';
   
   }
?>
```

This is Col1 and Col2:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC9Ys.jpg)

This is user Permissions:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbXsV.jpg)

VAR_EXPORT:

$Col2:

```
array ( 
  0 => array ( 'id' => '11', 'descricao' => 'documentos', 'id_empresa' => '1', 'estado' => '1', 'descricao_site' => 'Documentos', ), 
  1 => array ( 'id' => '14', 'descricao' => 'galerias', 'id_empresa' => '1', 'estado' => '1', 'descricao_site' => 'Galerias', ), 
  2 => array ( 'id' => '15', 'descricao' => 'registos', 'id_empresa' => '1', 'estado' => '1', 'descricao_site' => 'Registos', ), 
  3 => array ( 'id' => '16', 'descricao' => 'correspondencia', 'id_empresa' => '1', 'estado' => '1', 'descricao_site' => 'CorrespondÃªncia', ), 
  4 => array ( 'id' => '17', 'descricao' => 'portaria', 'id_empresa' => '1', 'estado' => '1', 'descricao_site' => 'Portaria', ), 
  5 => array ( 'id' => '18', 'descricao' => 'refeicoes', 'id_empresa' => '1', 'estado' => '1', 'descricao_site' => 'RefeiÃ§Ãµes', ), 
  6 => array ( 'id' => '19', 'descricao' => 'imghome', 'id_empresa' => '1', 'estado' => '1', 'descricao_site' => 'Imghome', ), 
  7 => array ( 'id' => '20', 'descricao' => 'imobilizado', 'id_empresa' => '1', 'estado' => '1', 'descricao_site' => 'Imobilizado', ), 
  8 => array ( 'id' => '21', 'descricao' => 'rh', 'id_empresa' => '1', 'estado' => '1', 'descricao_site' => 'RH', ),
)
```

$ModulosPermissaoFuncio:

```
array ( 
  0 => array ( 'id' => '73', 'uid' => '99999', 'id_modulo' => '18', 'id_empresa' => '1', ), 
  1 => array ( 'id' => '74', 'uid' => '99999', 'id_modulo' => '17', 'id_empresa' => '1', ), 
)
```

Comment: `$checked1` will keep being overwritten every time you loop. This is basic logic. Either assign the results of your tests to an array so you've got the whole set for later usage, or just echo each `<input type="checkbox` directly from inside the loop.

Comment: Yes, in my logic i is supposed to be overwritten, the problem is that it would be overwritten on permssion 3 and 4 so checked1 would be "checked", and show checkbox checked, but it doesn't put that tag on the input.

Comment: `supposed to be overwritten`...really, why? That seems to be the main cause of the problem. From what you've said, you probably need to break the inner loop once you've found the item you want, but the exact solution is not clear - it would help if we could see the contents of `$col2` and `$modulosPermissaoFuncio` so we understand what data we're processing. Can you please output them using [var_export](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) please and then post the data (or if it's too big, a small sample) in the question, for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: Edited the post with images from database permissions and col1 and col2.

So user id is (uid) 99999 and has 2 permissions, 17 and 18, which reflects on col2 as Portaria and Refeiçoes.

Using my logic it should check those 2 checkboxes right?

It should overwrite when the condition is met, so the checkbox is checked or not.

Added var_export too. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is because you're not breaking the loop once you've found the matching entry in `$modulosPermissaoFuncio`.

e.g. in the case of the item `'id' => '18'` from `$col2`, the inner `foreach` loop will find the entry `'id_modulo' => '18'` in `$ModulosPermissaoFuncio` the first time it loops, and sets `$checked1` to `checked`. So far so good.

The problem is, *it doesn't stop there*. It loops again, but this time `$value["id"]` doesn't match `$checkedModulo["id_modulo"]` (the latter is `17` this time), so it goes into the `else` block and sets `$checked1` back to empty. Therefore, by the time you come to output the checkbox, `$checked1` has been reset to empty.

So that's what I meant in the comments where I said it's overwriting the value, and you need to break out of the loop once you've found the value you want.

This should fix it:

```
if ($value["id"] == $checkedModulo["id_modulo"]){
    $checked1 = "checked";
    break;
}
```

Working demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/8d38b83063d8480eb2443b1dfb0a4a83512b546b

Relevant documentation: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php

Comment: Thank you ADyson, tried to add the breaks but in the wrong place. 
Thank you very much!!